# Mysql using sum to percentage

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add another column which gives me an percentage of `count vs sum`, so basically the `value 1` will have 25% and `value 2` is 75%, others will be 100%

```
+----------+--------------------+-------+------+
| type     | value              | count | sum  |
+----------+--------------------+-------+------+
|      600 | 1                  |     1 |    4 |
|      600 | 2                  |     3 |    4 |
|      601 | 2                  |     1 |    1 |
|      602 | 1                  |     1 |    1 |
|      603 | 8                  |     1 |    1 |


SELECT a1.type, 
    a1.value, 
    COUNT(*) AS count,
     (SELECT SUM(a2.total) AS sum 
        FROM (SELECT a3.type, 
            a3.value, 
            count(*) AS total 
                FROM Answer AS a3 
            GROUP BY 1) AS a2
        WHERE a2.type = a1.type      
    GROUP BY type) AS sum
    FROM Answer a1
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

I'm having trouble of adding this part:

```
(count / sum * 100 AS percentage)
```

How it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN with the subquery instead of using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a1.type, a1.value, COUNT(*) AS count, a2.sum, COUNT(*)/sum * 100 AS percentage
FROM Answer a1
JOIN (SELECT type, SUM(total) AS sum
      FROM (SELECT type, value, COUNT(*) AS total
            FROM Answer
            GROUP BY type, value) AS sub1
      GROUP BY type) AS a2
ON a1.type = a2.type
GROUP BY a1.type, a1.value
```

Another way is to put your original query into a subquery:

```
SELECT type, value, count, sum, count/sum*100 AS percentage
FROM (<original query>) AS x
```

You need to do this because you can't refer to aliases from expressions in the same `SELECT` clause.